# Click event on button doesn't seem to fire

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not new to HTML or JavaScript, though I don't use them often. I am, however, very new to PHP, and am currently facing a weird issue when trying to get a click event on a button in my HTML which is imbedded in PHP:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="function() { alert('Moo!'); }">Some button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Nothing happens when I click on the button. Yes, there's of course more markup in the original, but it's not relevant to my question. The W3C markup validation service says there are no errors, and when I alert moo from a script at the bottom of the body tag it works fine as well. It looks like the click event doesn't fire... Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your anonymous function syntax. You're using a function definition, but you're not immediately invoking it, or giving it a name, so the browser doesn't have anything to do with it.

If you want it immediately invoked when clicked you might try rewriting the button section like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="(function() { alert('Moo!'); })();">Some button</button>
```

But my personal preference would be to write it into a named function and call it as the handler instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you define a function and do not execute it. Do not wrap it in a function.

```
onclick="alert('Moo!');"
```

If you wrap it in a function. you would need to execute it.

```
onclick="(function() { alert('Moo!'); })()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have anonymous functions in the inline event handler - use `alert("Moo")`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="alert('Moo!')">Some button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

You could also use a named function:

```js
function moo() {
  alert("Moo!");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="moo()">Some button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

And even an IIFE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Blah</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="(function() { alert('Moo!'); })()">Some button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind actions in `onclick` attribute in 3 ways:

1. `<button type="button" onclick="alert('Moo!');">Some button</button>`
2. Make a function in JS code. `<button type="button" onclick="someFunc()">Some button</button>`
3. Using [closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp): `<button type="button" onclick="(function() { alert('Moo!'); })()">Some button</button>`

`